# Code Coverage Tool

Tags: asp.net, performance, unit-testing, web, code-coverage

I have an ASP.Net application and I want to learn which lines of code are covered by unit tests. (Test team is testing in the system all the time, but I do not know which parts of the system are being tested)

Do you know of any tools for this purpose? It should be able to work on web applications and also  show me the code coverage rates, with function or class names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Visual Studio 2012, if your version permits.

To do this go to the Test > Analyze Code Coverage > All Tests it will output your 'Code Coverage Results' like this:

[image: Screen grab]

Selecting 'Show Code Coverage Coloring' (circled in red above) results in the following:

[image]

Which highlights that `Method2` is not covered.

See here for more detailed info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx

There is also a paid for tool from jet brains, dotcover.

http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/

I have not used that but I'm sure someone else reading has and will be able to advise you.

Comment: Note that code coverage is not available in all versions of Visual Studio. In Visual Studio 2013 it is available only in Pro or Ultimate editions.

Comment: Actually I think it's only Ultimate and Premium for VS2012 [Comparison](http://www.microway.com.au/microsoft/visual-studio-2012-compare-editions.php)

Comment: I know it but I am using Visual Studo 2010 in my project and now I can not upgrade the latest version of vs.